# JFrame opening a JApplet

Tags: java, swing, japplet

I am making a program in java which the JButton in JFrame will hide the JFrame and run a JApplet

I have done something like

```
OpenButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                hide();
                JApplet startGame = new MainApplet();

                startGame.init();
                startGame.start();
        }
});
```

what am I doing wrong? thank you

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Applet are not intended to do that. Are you sure you cannot extract the game from the applet so you can use it both with a jframe application and a japplect

Comment: @userNNNN "..what am I doing wrong?"  The 1st thing is not supplying enough information.  For starters, what exactly happens when you call that code, as opposed to what does happen?  BTW - did you realize that the applet needs to be added to a parent container before it will be visible?  The JRE does that automatically for embedded applets, and applets launched using Java Web Start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution you are looking for is a separate class for the main logic and top level containers JFrame and JApplet.

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel { ... your game here ... }
public class GameApplet extends JApplet {  
   private final GamePanel game;
   public GameApplect(GamePanel gamePanel) {
      this.game = game;
      super.add(game);
   }

   public void init() {
      ... applet init ... 
      this.game.init();
   }

   public void start() {
      ... applet start ...
      this.game.start(); 
   }
}

public class GameWindow extends JFrame {  
   private final GamePanel game;
   public GameApplect(GamePanel gamePanel) {
      this.game = game;
      super.add(game);
   }

   public void init() {
      ... frame init ... 
      this.game.init();
   }

   public void start() {
      ... frame start ...
      this.game.start(); 
   }
}
```

Then you can launch the game window instead of GameApplet on button click. If you are already running inside an applet or a window, you don't need to create separate GameApplet and GamePanel classes. You can just add the GamePanel to whichever container you want.